# Can I enter Croatia with single entry visa Schengen?

Tags: visas, schengen, greece, croatia

I am traveling first to Greece then to Croatia. But I have Schengen with single entry. So is it allowed to enter Croatia with this visa?

Answer (score 1):

No, your visa will not allow you to enter Croatia. To enter Croatia with a Schengen visa, the visa must be valid for at least two entries, see ['Visa requirements overview'](http://www.mvep.hr/en/consular-information/visas/visa-requirements-overview/) from the Croatian Ministry of Foreign and European Affairs.